# TensorFlow - ValueError: features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to write a model with TensorFlow that utilizes the premade DNNClassifier in order to classify iris flowers.

```
BATCH_SIZE=100
TRAIN_STEPS=1000

def main(unused_argv):
  # Load training and eval data
  iris = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("iris")
  data = iris.data
  labels = iris.target
  train_data = data[:100]
  train_labels = labels[:100]
  eval_data = data[100:]
  eval_labels = labels[100:]
  # Feature columns
  feature_columns = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="SepalLength"),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="SepalWidth"),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="PetalLength"),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="PetalWidth")
  ]
  # Build DNN with 2 hidden layers, 10 neurons each
  classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=[10, 10], n_classes=3)
  # Train model
  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x=train_data,
    y=train_labels,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True
  )
  classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=TRAIN_STEPS)
  # Evaluate model
  eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x=eval_data,
    y=eval_labels,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False
  )
  eval_results = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
  print(eval_results)
```

I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s.

As far as I understand feature columns they should be a list. What is wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

What is your tensorflow version?

According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3331), if you use 1.4 or lower this error can be solved by upgrading.